# What are opencv_ffmpeg and opencv_world for?

Tags: opencv

I am a novice in OpenCV and start learning from now on.
From the zipped file downloaded from the official site, we have

```
opencv_ffmpeg341_64.dll
opencv_world341.dll
opencv_world341d.dll
```

in `c:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\`

However in `c:\opencv\build\bin\`, there are only

```
opencv_ffmpeg341.dll
opencv_ffmpeg341_64.dll
```

As far as I know, the application only needs either one of these files in `c:\opencv\build\bin\`.

## Question

What are the following files for?

```
opencv_world341.dll
opencv_world341d.dll
```

I also knew that `d` means debug.

Comment: [ffmpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) | "World" is just one DLL holding all the OpenCV modules, making it easier to ship (I suppose). The alternative is to have one DLL per module. (FFMPEG is always separate due to licencing issues)

Comment: @DanMašek: `opencv_ffmpeg` contains all the OpenCV modules and MPEG modules but `opencv_world` only contains all the OpenCV modules. Is it what you meant?

Comment: No. `opencv_ffmpeg` contains the code of a third party library used to work with video files, and this one is always standalone (and with no debug variant) since it needs to be loaded dynamically at runtime. `opencv_world` is an amalgamation of all the OpenCV modules. It's the alternative to having dozens of dlls (core, imgproc, highgui, etc.)

Comment: @DanMašek: OK. But why is there no `opencv_world` in `c:\opencv\build\bin\` ? It looks strange to me because we also need `opencv_world` , right?